# Deployment vb.net and crystal report to client PC

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, window

I'm using window 10, VN.NET 2015 with Crystal Report and Oracle 11g at PC-A, Windows 10, Oracle 11g at Pc-B.

I published the installation package and run on PC-B and it is working fine, connected with database but the report is not working and I received the message:

> the type initializer for 'crystaldecisions.shared.sharedutils' threw
>   an exception

These are the dll.deploy files included in the application files folder:

[image]

Please let me know how I can fix this problem.

[image]

[image: project data]

[image: My Connection]

### **Updated**

[image: connection code]

[image: New One]

Comment: this file may be not deploy, to check go to in the project, then just search this dll used or if not found then search in the code this dll name where you will find the reference via Using keyword at the top in the page

Comment: i have this file "CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll"  in "\bin\Debug" and "CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll.deploy" in "Application Files" but i i don't have "crystaldecisions.shared.sharedutils" file , .....

Comment: that will be the namespace which is in this dll. Just check these link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374681/the-type-initializer-for-crystaldecisions-shared-sharedutils-threw-an-exceptio, 
   https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/417334/Issue-related-to-Crystal-Reports,

Comment: I installed "CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_22" then issue resolved .. but now i have another issue ....  when i run report i got this msg "crystal window form viewer"  ----"Failed to load database information"

Comment: ok, so for this, just try to connect db from your report in local pc. and reply that Are you able to do this?

Comment: yes i can connect and run all reports on my local pc  (development PC) and also only one report is running on client pc but other reports giving the same msg ...

Comment: which one that you just checked right now.

Comment: i just found one difference , the report ruining on client Pc , have connection "database Expert --- project data --- DataSet1, and the other reports which  msg "crystal window form viewer" ----"Failed to load database information" have have connection "database Expert --- My Connection --- Sureguide" ,... i think this is the problem ??? how i can resolve this ??

Comment: yes, by default whatever credential you gave while creating CR, its preserve with the connection string. When you publish or run on another machine, its try to access DB based on credential preserve and if not able to access, then its throw above error

Comment: you can check that how to set credentials : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255835/crystal-report-viewer-not-accepting-login-info

Comment: the report is running is this didn't set credentials at report level , i just add data set in project and have connection "database Expert --- project data --- DataSet1, the only difference i found in report ....  "database Expert --- My Connection --- Sureguide"  not ruining ....  database Expert --- project data --- DataSet1, running

Comment: are you solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your code for credential code and for the actual credential value you will set in your web.config/app.config file. and after that publish and deploy with new credentials which CR automatically update it at runtime.

```
ConnectionInfo crconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    ReportDocument cryrpt = new ReportDocument();
    TableLogOnInfos crtablelogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    TableLogOnInfo crtablelogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

    Tables CrTables;

    crconnectioninfo.ServerName = "localhost";
    crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "dbclients";
    crconnectioninfo.UserID = "ssssssss";
    crconnectioninfo.Password = "xxxxxxx";
```

Check this links :
[How to set database login infos (connection info) for crystal report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002957/how-to-set-database-login-infos-connection-info-for-crystal-report)

[How to stop crystal report viewer from asking login credentials when opening subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709438/how-to-stop-crystal-report-viewer-from-asking-login-credentials-when-opening-sub)

Comment: this code not working .... i can't understand why my one report running without any credential value  ???

Comment: I written above just see

Comment: this code not working with vb.net 2015 -- giving me error , can you plz verify your code.

Comment: i have a connection name "sgcnn" in my main module and call the connect at the form where report run .... now i tried to copy your code "sgcnn.ServerName"  but its not there ....

Comment: if the dll is not there when you get error, just ctrl+spacebar which suggest to include namespace and add it (this is only happened when dll added in your project), other wise add dll which is required. In my case I added 4or 5 CR dll in which one of them have this functionality to add db credentials and connection string. I will check that dll

Comment: the error shows that variable not define, just declare as in the my code ConnectionInfo crconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo(); and still you get error for "ConnectionInfo" , then add dll which automatically .net suggest when you mouse over on the "ConnectionInfo"

Comment: i just add "new one" coding screen  plz see,  i did this still have little issue or some thing missing ....

Comment: Hi @EjazSarwar, that is not required, if you see my first link in the answer. That is required when you have multiple tables rather than stored procedure. Ideally its not required, just check without that variable.